# Order table by specific values in a UNION Query

Tags: sql

I have a query that needs to order a column by a specific value. Currently for the act_code Charges have a '+' value, Payments have a '-' value and Awards have a '=' value. I need the order to be Charges, Payments, Awards but I get Payments, Charges, Awards. I get "Invalid Column Name tcodes.act_code" when I run my query. Here is my query:

```
    SELECT tmptract.soc_sec, 
           name.last_name, 
           name.first_name, 
           name.mi, 
           address.st_addr, 
           address.add_addr, 
           address.add_add2, 
           address.city, 
           address.state, 
           address.zip, 
           tcodes.act_code, 
           '' as employee_soc_sec, 
           2 as bill_type
      FROM tmptract, 
           name, 
           address, 
           tcodes, 
           transact
     WHERE tmptract.soc_sec = name.soc_sec
       AND address.soc_sec = name.soc_sec
       AND tcodes.tcodes = transact.tcodes
       AND tmptract.token = '#session.token#'
  ORDER BY name.last_name, 
           name.first_name, 
           name.mi, 
           tmptract.soc_sec, 
           bill_type,
           (CASE 
              WHEN tcodes.act_code = '+' THEN '1'
              WHEN tcodes.act_code = '-' THEN '2'
              WHEN tcodes.act_code = '=' THEN '3' 
              ELSE tcodes.act_code 
            END)
```

Comment: also, there isn't a  join between address table and tcodes table?

Answer (score 0):

While selecting the code, you would have to do the same..

```
SELECT tmptract.soc_sec, 
           name.last_name, 
           name.first_name, 
           name.mi, 
           address.st_addr, 
           address.add_addr, 
           address.add_add2, 
           address.city, 
           address.state, 
           address.zip, 
           tcodes.act_code,
            (CASE 
              WHEN tcodes.act_code = '+' THEN '1'
              WHEN tcodes.act_code = '-' THEN '2'
              WHEN tcodes.act_code = '=' THEN '3' 
              ELSE tcodes.act_code 
            END) as TCode, 
           '' as employee_soc_sec, 
           2 as bill_type
      FROM tmptract, 
           name, 
           address, 
           tcodes, 
           transact
     WHERE tmptract.soc_sec = name.soc_sec
       AND address.soc_sec = name.soc_sec
       AND tcodes.tcodes = transact.tcodes
       AND tmptract.token = '#session.token#'
  ORDER BY name.last_name, 
           name.first_name, 
           name.mi, 
           tmptract.soc_sec, 
           bill_type,
           TCode
```